# What is the origin of the idiom "Put on a clinic"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin

I was rather fascinated by the idiom **[put on a clinic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20on%20a%20clinic)** (meaning *to perform extremely well*) when I heard it used today for what I'm sure was the first time, because it sounded so cool. More than that, I was intrigued by its origin, and it's certainly not too easy to trace its roots without laboring a bit. Which I did: consulted a handful of online dictionaries. Sadly, to no avail. I'm afraid (and a bit embarrassed to say) that I've virtually exhausted my resources. I do possess offline dictionaries and a title on word etymologies as well, but I know they won't be of much service in this regard.

Could anyone please shed some light on the origin of this beautiful idiom?

Comment: Can you give an example of where this was used (plus a link to the source)? I've never heard this before and so I need some context of where it was used.

Comment: You can at least type out the dialog around the use of the idiom. Or rather give us the chance to judge if it is an idiom or if it is just a one-off.

Comment: @Mitch - M-W defines the expression as an idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helps immensely.

Comment: Can we rule out that it doesn't mean something like "fooled the doctors"? "He wasn't sick; he was just putting us on. He put on a clinic."

Comment: I’ve always understood it to mean, “He was so far above everyone else, it was like he was their instructor demonstrating how to do it right.” It’s similar to saying he gave them a lesson or ran a camp for them.

Comment: This is an EXTREMELY common expression in sports, to the point where its annoying. OP doesn't need to prove its not one-off.

Comment: The reason it's common in sports is that there really are "clinics" for sports. Pitching clinics. coaching clinics, kicking clinics, etc., where people pay a fee to be trained by an expert. The point of the expression is that the person is demonstrating skill which greatly exceeds that needed to defeat the opponent, just as a teacher is presumed to be more skilled than the students.

Comment: There's a similar expression of "put on a hill" as a solution for if you're feeling cold while exercising.  I've heard it in relation to cycling, but running etc would be valid too.  Probably a combination of "put on a coat" and the idea of exercising harder to warm up.

Comment: Downvoted because it's not an idiom but an intelligible metaphor, as the answer from @OwenReynolds states.  **put on** is the phrasal verb we find in **put on a show**, **put on an instructional demonstration** and **clinic** can refer to a place where patients are given medical care and medical professionals train people who are new to the profession.

Comment: @TimR Downvote well taken. Thanks to you and OwenReynolds for enlightening me. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The original question asked about the idiom *put on a clinic* to mean "to perform exceptionally well." While the term originated with medical clinics and was transferred, as OED notes, to non-medical sessions "for instruction in or the study of a particular subject", the idiomatic use of demonstrating how to do something well through performance, rather than through formal instruction, came later.

It has been used extensively in sports. The earliest I've found is a 1936 article about a pitcher with the Little Rock Travelers of the minor league Southern Association in a game against the Birmingham Barons:

> Lee Rogers is one of the best left-handed curve ball pitchers in the league. He stepped out Monday with everything under control and proceeded to put on a pitching clinic.
> -- Zipp Newman, *Birmingham News*, April 29, 1936, p18

Comment: It's interesting to note that not very many dictionaries list this meaning of _clinical_: **US, informal : done or performed with excellence and precision : EXEMPLARY**
_In the meantime Bryant … continued his clinical shooting, which has allowed him to more than double his scoring average …_
— Alexander Wolff   Could there be any connection between this usage of _clinical_ and the idiom?

Comment: @user405662: Yes, but more of an indirect connection.  The use of "clinical" in that sense always made me think of the sterility and precision of a medical clinic (treatment centre, especially surgical...  which is a synonym of clinical in the context you're talking about.)  "Clinical precision" or "clinical shooting" doesn't make *me* think of a sports group-teaching session, while "put on a clinic" most certainly does.  (I was already familiar with both usages, including the literal meaning of e.g. "throwing clinic" for Ultimate [frisbee] players, and the idiomatic meaning.)

Comment: This makes sense to me. Sometimes we'll say that someone "showed everyone how to do" something, and this sounds similar to instructing in a clinic.

Comment: I've found an example of the term in a metaphoric sense from nine years earlier than the baseball sense. This one if from politics. It refers to a cleaning up of corruption in Indianapolis.

"So Indiana feels that it is putting on a clinic for the rest of the country, letting it in on the surgical operation that has been necessary to eliminate the state's political ills." -- Owen L. Scott, "Indianapolis Is Hopeful Today," Yonkers Statesman, November 9, 1927, p19. (Syndicated article also appeared elsehwere)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ken Liss and others. Your comments supplement the answer nicely.

Comment: Hello, @Ken Liss. I happened on your profile visiting this question after a notification popped up. I'm gravitated toward folks who show a keen interest in words, their origins, and the stories that surround them. I must say I'm impressed with your fervor for words. I'm a novice in this regard, but have loved words my entire life. Could you please recommend some brilliant books on 'words' and 'word etymologies'? Titles as you cherish yourself and love to visit again and again. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I'd call it a metaphor. Like a metaphor, anyone hearing it can figure out the intent and think it seems clever, and anyone who gets the idea can make up a new version.

The overall metaphor is that it looks like we're watching an excellent instructor teaching in a classroom setting. I suppose that's the origin, but not in the sense of how an idiom has one particular place where the phrase made sense. Older variants are the pitcher might *show us how it's done*, or *school* us in how to strike someone out, or *demonstrated* his pitching skill (as in -- it looked as if he was giving a demonstration, instead of playing in a real game), or put on a *fine display* of pitching skill. *Put on a clinic* is just more in the same vein. We could go on and invent "she gave us a *master class* in pitching".

Comment: I like that analysis although I'm sure there's a history behind the idiom.

Comment: @user405662 I'm saying it's NOT an idiom. An idiom is so unnatural that it has to have a specific origin for where it made sense. A metaphor like this is so obvious that many people would have independently said it without any deep reason, just that clinic and class are similar words.

Answer (score 8):

It stems from a shift of meaning and emphasis

> [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/clinic)
>
> clinic (n.)
> 1620s, "bedridden person, one confined to his bed by sickness," from French clinique (17c.), from Latin clinicus "physician that visits patients in their beds," from Greek klinike (techne) "(practice) at the sickbed," from klinikos "of the bed," from kline "bed, couch, that on which one lies," from suffixed form of PIE root *klei- "to lean."
>
> Also "one who defers baptism until the death-bed" (1660s). Sense of "private hospital" is from 1884, from German Klinik in this sense, itself from French clinique, via the notion of "bedside medical education, examination of a patient by an instructor in the presence of students."
>
> The modern sense thus reverses the classical one, in which the "clinic" came to the patient. General sense of "conference for group instruction in something" is from 1919.

The idea of group instruction was extended from medicine to other areas:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clinic)
>
> Clinic:
>
> a group meeting devoted to the analysis and solution of concrete problems or to the acquiring of specific skills or knowledge

The person offering or providing such a clinic would necessarily by knowledgeable and authoritative, so would become respected. Putting on a clinic became a symbol of such success.

The idiom *putting on …* occurs elsewhere as in *putting on a show*, *putting on airs*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-on-something)
>
> Put on:
>
> to do an activity, esp. one that others can watch:

Comment: The sense and usage you suggest look quite plausible. It would be interesting to know where and when this usage started.

Answer (score 5):

clinic (n.)

> *Transferred*—An institution, class, conference, etc., for instruction in or the
> study of a particular subject; a seminar. ***Chiefly* U.S.**
>
> **1919**   *British Manufacturer* Nov. 30/2   In order to solve this difficult problem in economic diagnosis, we need a clinic just as the
> doctor does.
>
> OED, with earliest citation (see Anton's answer for more on the etymology).

---

> Regular meetings are held the third Thursday of each month, usually at
> one of the offices or preceded by a dinner at one of the hotels.  A
> committee has been appointed to **put on a clinic** about March first.
> [*Bulletin of the Colorado State Dental Association,* Volumes 1-2](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bulletin_of_the_Colorado_State_Dental_As/NKe3AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22put%20on%20%20a%20clinic%22%20colorado&dq=%22put%20on%20%20a%20clinic%22%20colorado&printsec=frontcover)
> (Snippet View. The date on the Google search-results page (not always reliable) is 1917, so this example may be from 1917 or 1918)

A number of the earliest examples in Google Books for clinics being "put on" are from state dental associations.

Answer (score 0):

For me, as a non-native English speaker and German medical and fond of Basketball, I noticed in former times (when Dirk Nowitzki scored really well in the NBA and hit almost all of his shots) and until today, that this special idiom is being used when sportsmen are performing very well. In my ears the idiom sounds like "do it with the precision of a surgeon", and that's how I understand it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/419339)

Answer (score 0):

A "clinic" is a lesson, it is a master-class lesson for advanced practitioners of a sport or often a musical instrument. A master guitarist might tour around selling tickets to a "guitar clinic" small venue small numbers, it might include interviews, video, Q and A etc. If someone is putting on a "clinic" they are putting on a master level display.

Comment: This is an explanation of the idiom but not its origins, which is what the question was asking about. We need answers to be focused on answering the question. Do you have anything you can add about the origins?

Answer (score 0):

The earliest instance "of put on a clinic" that I've found in various database searches is from "[Missouri-Kansas-Oklahoma Ass'n's Annual Meeting](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.31951d00336538d&seq=1255&q1=%22put+on+a+clinic%22),"in *The Hotel Monthly* (December 1915):

> J. P. McGuire, of Armour & Co., **put on a clinic**, using a yearling wether mutton carcass, which an expert butcher dissected into market cuts, the lecturer explaining as the cutting was done. This clinic will be the subject of a special article in THE HOTEL MONTHLY.

Also, from "[Report of Oral Hygiene Committee O[ntario] D[ental] S[ociety]](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b4633356&seq=177&q1=%22put+on+a+clinic%22)," in *Oral Health* (May 1919):

> Mr. Putman, of the Agricultural Department of the Provincial Government, asked for the co-operation of the Committee to make an investigation of the school children of Streetsville, and **put on a clinic** for two days. The Committee complied with the request and Dr. Bothwell kindly took charge of this work.

And from "[Symposium on Health, Labor and Education—Infant Welfare Clinics](https://books.google.com/books?id=0apCAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22put+on+a+clinic%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjznP_pvbGBAxX5JkQIHYc4Al4Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20a%20clinic%22&f=false)," in *Proceedings of the first state conference of child welfare boards with the Board of Control. State Capitol, May 9 and 10, 1919, St. Paul, Minnesota* (1919):

> **Mrs. Johnson:** We attempted to **put on a clinic** without outside help, the doctors in town giving their services, and 406 children were brought in. Then the county welfare board took the list of defective children and tried to follow it up.

To sum up, an instance of "put on a clinic" from 1915 involves demonstrating professional mutton butchering at a regional hotel association meeting in St. Louis, Missouri. An instance of the phrase from 1919 refers to providing dentistry services to the children of a town in Ontario. And a second instance from 1919 involves an ad hoc effort to test children in St Paul, Minnesota, for tuberculosis and other diseases.

A fourth instance, from slightly later in 1919, appears to be the one cited in DjinTonic's answer. From "[The Pueblo County Dental Society](https://books.google.com/books?id=NKe3AAAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PP21&dq=%22put+on+a+clinic+about+March+first%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi98uvnvrGBAxVpLUQIHcp9BHEQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20a%20clinic%20about%20March%20first%22&f=false)," in *Bulletin of the Colorado State Dental Association* (December 1919):

> Regular meetings [of the Pueblo County Dental Society] are held the third Thursday of each month, usually at one of the offices, or preceded by a dinner at one of the hotels. A committee has been appointed to **put on a clinic** about March first.